# Redundant Data Centers

Tags: failover, datacenter

I currently have an ASP.NET web app running on a cluster in a data center talking to a SQL Server DB. I need to make this setup redundant with a hot-hot DB in another data center as well as a replicated web cluster.

What architectural options are available to setup this type of fail-over?

Comment: it depends on how current you want your data and how much data you will be transfering.

Comment: The idea is to keep two hot-hot SQL Server DB's at different physical locations so that if one goes down there is no interruption in service. Is this even possible?

Comment: real time synchronization isn't likely without high expenses, especially if you have a lot of data transferring around.  clustered failover servers w/ a quality san and reliable backup routines would be a much easier solution to implement.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, gotcha, I apologize, i'm a bit new here, this is an awesome site!

For the proposed solution I would recommend 3 tiers of redundancy in a multi-threaded setup.

Database-
Continue to use SQL in a cluster configuration, 2 nodes with a DRBD RAID10 pair of storage systems to keep the data up and running.  In the event of Datacenter failure (worst possible case) have a 3rd tier passive replica at another datacenter with transaction logs being shipped.

Web-
2 Web servers, local data stored on a seperate set of drives RAID1 or RAID10 depending on size and I/O.  Replicate data via Robocopy.
Added performance and requirement for 100%, incorporate dedicated load balancers in a pair.
Additional replica web server at a seperate datacenter.